# How to display this html structured json response in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, iphone, swiftui

I have this response from json
text:`"<p>Lorem ipsum</p><p><img src="url/some-image"></p>[[youtube]]<p>Here is youtube url show as embed</p>[[twitter]]<p>Same as youtube</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p>"`

How I can show that in my App, like on web? Can I do that with SwiftUI?
What I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Create a UIWebView() and connect it as an outlet. By doing this, it should load your HTML code directly on your Swift page. Hope this helps!

```
myWebView.loadHTMLString("<p>Lorem ipsum</p><p></p>[[youtube]]<p>Here is youtube url show as embed</p>[[twitter]]<p>Same as youtube</p><p>Lorem ipsum</p>", baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: You can try what they say in this forum as reference https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117348

Comment: @AvivFrenkel Thanks for the addition.